# Name of device with air capsule inside water

Tags: pressure, terminology, fluid-statics

Sorry for the title being so vague. I'm looking for the name of something in physics to do with pressure. It is a bottle of water with a small capsule with air inside it. When the bottle is squeezed, the capsule sinks, but when it is left alone, the capsule floats. Could anyone tell me what this is called, and hopefully how it works as well?

Comment: Closely related: (Cartesian diver) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322015/226902

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called a [Cartesian diver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_diver).

When you squeeze the bottle to increase the pressure, the dropper compresses and becomes more dense. If this increased density exceeds the density of water then the diver will sink.

Comment: It's not the density of the air that increases to exceed that of water - it's the average density of entire diver. The air density increases but not to nearly as much as water.

Comment: Of course, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the "diver" is a test tube with a perforated cork stop, so that, when the bottle is squeezed, water gets into the diver and it sinks.