# Titanic submersible implosion depth June 2023

Tags: acoustics

From noises/acoustic emissions monitored and data collected by US Coast Guard (or other agencies) was it possible to determine at what depth the fatal implosion occurred?

If time differences from three deep stations (in a vertical plane of the Atlantic) are known,  [Hyperbolic Navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_navigation) helps to determine the depth of implosion from sea level.

Comment: Titan related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769418/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769650/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769650/226902

Answer (score 1):

Radio waves (hyperbolic navigation) don't travel the same way as acoustic waves. The latter moves in a medium (water) that is in movement, with a velocity of nearly the same magnitude as the wave propagation velocity. This effect needs to be taken into account in the ray tracing. The same happens with sound in the atmosphere, where it can be carried by the wind. So you need to model temperature and wind (ocean currents) at least to do this.

Same problem arises when locating a meteor fragmentation event from the arrival times of sound waves to seismic stations. If you are interested in this topic, take a look at this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jastp.2021.105587.

Comment: Although good information may be included in your thesis, unfortunately not all of us speak (and read) Spanish. It may be beneficial to the general public to either summarise the relevant content in your answer or at least provide the most relevant resources (articles, textbooks or anything else) from your thesis. This way, people would be able to follow what you have done in your thesis but through the relevant bibliography.

Comment: @ZaellixA thanks for the suggestion. I have edited to include a paper in english.